# Applying Filter to one Chart only

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, visualization, powerbi-desktop

I have a small problem when applying the filter to only one graph, it is applied to all graphs on the page,
Is there a solution to put one filter for each graph or is there a better solution such as specifying the graphs related to the filter only.

[When i choose gender = All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Nty6.png)

[When i choose gender = male](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs5eP.png)

**Note**: I know that the reason the pie-chart does not appear is because it does not have a gender classification. My problem is applying the filter to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have used slicer as filter so you can disable filter for the graphs which you dont want filter with "Edit Interaction" option.

[image]